# Scala class accessing public var

Tags: scala

```
class Cliente() {
  var Prato: Prato
  var Bebidas: Set[Bebida]
  var Sobremesas: Set[Sobremesa]
}
```

If I call

```
cliente = new Cliente()
cliente.Prato = Pratos(opt)
```

I get

```
error: class Cliente needs to be abstract, since:
it has 3 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from class Cliente, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def Bebidas_=(x$1: Set[this.Bebida]): Unit = ???
  def Prato_=(x$1: this.Prato): Unit = ???
  def Sobremesas_=(x$1: Set[this.Sobremesa]): Unit = ???
```

I can't have public properties in scala?

Comment: You need to initialize your `var`'s, for example as `var Prato: Prato = _`, otherwise compiler considers these vars as unimplemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java land, we're accustomed to having defaults for uninitialised fields.  In Scala land, however, we can't.

We're forced to assign values - even if they are `null` or `_` - rather than allowing them to default to `null` like in the Java land.  This goes some way in avoiding the `NullPointerException` problem we have in the Java land.

Comment: You may assign nulls as default values in scala, in fact _ for refs is actually null. This doesn't solve any NPE problem, it is just other semantics/syntax.

Comment: @dmitry I've just edited the answer and hopefully it's clearer. It's great we can do refactoring with our answers and we get to keep their history too. The GitHub of technical penmanship! :)